# How can i make this button work, it's not redirecting now

Tags: html

i've been editing a html website and want to add the a href tag to a button. Codewise everything seems well but the button doesn't do anything. Here the code:

a class="scroll btn btn-gradient btn-rounded btn-large" href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Visit google

Please help :(

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Edit your question as You need to provide the surrounding code. The problem isn’t in the code line provided

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" class="scroll btn btn-gradient btn-rounded btn-large">Visit google</a>
```

It looks like you forgot to close off the anchor tag.

Comment: No i did, the line goes <a class="scroll btn btn-gradient btn-rounded btn-large" href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Visit google</a>